# Less vs Fewer: what kind of problem is this? Syntax, usage, grammar?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

If someone consistently misused *fewer* and *less* in their speech, would you say they have a problem with syntax, usage, grammar or something else?

What class of problem does fewer/less fall into?

Comment: Grammar/syntax (acceptable constructions and attempts to formulate rules) is certainly involved. However, logic isn't always followed here. 'That's one less problem to deal with' is arguably 'more correct' than  'That's one fewer problem / problem fewer to deal with' on the grounds of **idiomaticity**.